# Can TestCafe run &#39;remote&#39; tests behind a proxy?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a UI set up for users to select tests. Once they choose, I want to start a test runner with the 'remote' browser and give the user the URL so that they can watch the tests perform live in their browser.

In Heroku, there is no way to access non-standard ports. I attempted to use express-http-proxy so that I could create a route to where TestCafe was running on localhost. I was unable to get the proxy to work for TestCafe (though it did work for other pages).

To rule out issues with the proxy, I will be attempting to route to TestCafe by using nginx as soon as possible.

**Is it even possible to run remote TestCafe tests behind a proxy?**

In other words, I want to point example.com/remotetest to the TestCafe runner at localhost:3789 and watch a test run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestCafe requires [2 ports](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/configuration-file.html#port1-port2) for running. If Heroku doesn't support non-standard ports, you cannot set-up running TestCafe tests in `remote` mode.